# Is it possible to have multiple output files for a map-reduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In my input file i have a column as country. Now, my task is to place records of a particular country into a separate file naming with that country. Is this possible to do in Map-reduce.!
Please share your ideas regarding this.

Comment: Have you tried 'tee' to clone the output stream.

Comment: No @Marichyasana Actually i don't know about this, Can you elaborate

Comment: What version of hadoop are you using, and are you looking for an old API (`mapred`) or new API (`mapreduce`) based solution?

Comment: @Rav... "tee" is a unix command, look at the man page.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is, in hadoop you can use [`MultipleOutputFormat`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputFormat.html) to do exactly that, using its [`generateFileNameForKeyValue`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputFormat.html#generateFileNameForKeyValue%28K,%20V,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

Using your country names as keys and the records as values this should work exactly as you need it to.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the new API , you should look at the [MultipleOutputs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html) class. There is an example inside this class.

Usage pattern for job submission:

```
    Job job = new Job();

    FileInputFormat.setInputPath(job, inDir);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outDir);

    job.setMapperClass(MOMap.class);
    job.setReducerClass(MOReduce.class);
    ...

    // Defines additional single text based output 'text' for the job
    MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "text", TextOutputFormat.class,
    LongWritable.class, Text.class);

    // Defines additional sequence-file based output 'sequence' for the job
    MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "seq",
      SequenceFileOutputFormat.class,
      LongWritable.class, Text.class);
    ...

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
    ...
```

Usage in Reducer:

```
    String generateFileName(K k, V v) {
       return k.toString() + "_" + v.toString();
    }

    public class MOReduce extends
       Reducer {
         private MultipleOutputs mos;
         public void setup(Context context) {
          ...
              mos = new MultipleOutputs(context);
          }

         public void reduce(WritableComparable key, Iterator values,
                Context context)
                throws IOException {
          ...
     mos.write("text", , key, new Text("Hello"));
     mos.write("seq", LongWritable(1), new Text("Bye"), "seq_a");
     mos.write("seq", LongWritable(2), key, new Text("Chau"), "seq_b");
     mos.write(key, new Text("value"), generateFileName(key, new Text("value")));
     ...
      }

    public void cleanup(Context) throws IOException {
         mos.close();
     ...
    }
   }
```

Comment: Care to explain the above code?? Everybody has access to the stock documentation. People come here for explanations to that.