# how to create output files from hadoop mapreduce program?

Tags: mapreduce, output, hadoop2

I am new to hadoop2.60. I have written a MapReduce algorithm.
Data set is like below
1  loan  1234

2  loan  234

1  asd   1234

1  aqw   1234

1  asde  1267

2  qwer  1246

I want that if firstColumn is 1, then all the data of that line should go to file1-output
else all the data shuld go to file2-output.

How to achieve this in map-reduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that. This can be achieved by [MultipleOutputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputFormat.html) and using its [generateFileNameForKeyValue](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputFormat.html#generateFileNameForKeyValue%28K,%20V,%20java.lang.String%29).

Using the if conditions and MultipleOutputFormat this can be achieved easily.

You can see this for more examples. [Is it possible to have multiple output files for a map-reduce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16438615/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-output-files-for-a-map-reduce)

I hope I could answer your questions.

Comment: Hello Rachit. Thanks ...Do you have complete code for the same?

Comment: I don't have it right now, But I can surely work on something in a few days and post it. Also can you please accept the answer. Thank You.